# Android bound service, what happen when activity unbound it?

Tags: android, service, android-service

I have my main activity that can bind a service and call a service method.

The service method start a thread (in service) that download data and store them in db. At the end of download the thread can be restarted.

What happen if activity call unbindService (i.e. in onPause)? Service is destroyed and thread stopped or the service is destroyed when all task end?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the service was previously started using the `startService()` method and then bound to it, after unbind the service will continue running.

If you just started the service by using `bindService()` which creates the service if it is not running after unbind if no other `Activity` is bound to the service, the service will stop.

Comment: The service is started using bindService(), but when Activity unbind it same threads in service can still run, my question is, what happen to these tasks? Do they finish or are they killed?

Comment: The Threads will continue to run. You need to stop them. You must override the Services onStop() method and there you should stop the threads that are currently being executed.